Magento 2 : How To Show Custom Notice Message Before Payment Step on Checkout
I want to show alert box to customer after I click on "Next" button. if the Cart Subtotal is more than $100

I try to put this function in Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml but nothing hapenned.
    $(document).on('click', '.button.action.continue.primary', function (event) {`
    
    var orderTotal = parseFloat($('.totals.sub.price').text().replace('$', ''));

    if (orderTotal > 100) {
        alert({
            title: $.mage.__('Order Total Alert'),
            content: $.mage.__('Your Order Total exceeds $100.'),
            actions: {
                always: function () {
                }
            }
        });
    } else {default action
        $(this).off('click').trigger('click');
    }
});

did I do something wrong?

You need to create mixin for Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator for method next which trigger when customer clicks on Next step
let's create a small module i.e.Pawan_CheckoutJs

app/code/Pawan/CheckoutJs/registration.php

<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pawan_CheckoutJs',
    __DIR__
);


app/code/Pawan/CheckoutJs/etc/module.xml

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pawan_CheckoutJs"/>
</config>


app/code/Pawan/CheckoutJs/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
config: {
        mixins: {
             'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator': {
                 'Pawan_CheckoutJs/js/model/step-navigator-mixin': true
             }
        }
    }
};


app/code/Pawan/CheckoutJs/view/frontend/web/js/model/step-navigator-mixin.js

define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
], function (wrapper,$,totals,alert) {
    'use strict';

    return function (stepNavigator) {
        stepNavigator.next = wrapper.wrapSuper(stepNavigator.next, function () {
            this._super();
            console.log("llll");
            var subtotal = parseFloat(totals.totals()['subtotal']);
            console.log(subtotal);
            if(subtotal > 100){
                alert({
                    title: $.mage.__('Some title'),
                    content: $.mage.__('Some content'),
                    actions: {
                        always: function(){}
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return stepNavigator;
    };
});

You can download module from https://github.com/pawan/module-sample-magento2/tree/main/module-checkout-js here.
Hope above will help
